# Overloading operator <<. Error: Invalid operands to binary expression

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am trying to overload a << operator, but I am having weird problem. More precisely there is error:

*Invalid operands to binary expression ('ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream') and 'Team')*

where Team is my class name.

However my friend checked my code and he said that it's working for him. I am coding using Xcode on Mac.

I suppose that it's something with the compiler, isn't it?

That's my code divided into main, .hpp file and .cpp file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>  
#include "team.hpp"
int main()
{
    Team Legia = {"Legia Warszawa", "Warszawa", 283.5, 2, 42};
    Team Jagiellonia = {"Jagiellonia Bialystok", "Bialystok", 34.4, 1, 45};
    Legia.print();
    Jagiellonia.print();

    cout << Legia;
    cout << Jagiellonia;

    return 0;
}
```

.hpp file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Team {
private:
    char *name;
    char *location;
    double budget;
    int place;
    int points;
public:
    Team();
    Team(const char*, const char*, double, int, int);

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Team &team);

};
```

.cpp file

```
#include "team.hpp"
#include <iostream> 
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;


Team::Team(const char *_name, const char *_location, double _budget, int _place, int _points)
{
    name = new char[strlen(_name)+1];
    strcpy(name, _name);
    location = new char[strlen(_location)+1];
    strcpy(location, _location);
    budget = _budget;
    place = _place;
    points = _points;
}

Team::Team()
{
    name = new char[4];
    location = new char[8];
    strcpy(name, "name");
    strcpy(location, "location");
    budget = 0;
    place = 0;
    points = 0;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Team &team)
{
    out << "Informations about " << team.name << ": " << endl
    << "Location: " << team.location << endl
    << "Budget: " << team.budget << " millions (PLN)" << endl
    << "Place: " << team.place << endl
    << "Points: " << team.points << endl << endl;

    return out;
}
```

The whole code without formatting:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7f0681a380324222

Comment: You need to show the code. Also include the full error message in the question.

Comment: You should always post your code as formated text in the question itself here on SO, don't link to external sources/sites. They might become invalid later and the question would be incomplete. See how to make a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry, but firewalls are blocking me from accessing your link.  No posted code == no help.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I have posted most important code parts.

Comment: This compiles and runs ok on the all the newer version of gcc and clang that I tried. [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/9vyOn8mLiJulcsGx). What compiler are you using?

Comment: BTW, you should alleviate yourself of headaches and reduce debugging time by using `std::string` for text instead of character arrays.

Comment: @super I am using Xcode 9.2, but I can't find the way to check what compiler exactly it is. I will try to do that once more. But as far as I know it's Clang

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I know about strings, however in this code I am obliged to use them represented in c-style

Comment: I have created a new project and just moved everything from the old one to the new one and now everything works fine. Weird